# how to Login with stored procedure in webservice Window phone 8

Tags: c#, web-services, stored-procedures, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make a Windows 8 mobile application web service where the user gets registered, logs in, uploads a picture, etc.

I have created my database with a stored procedure. The registration code is working but I can't make the login work.

Here is the code:

```
**Webservce** 
public string Login(string username, string password)
    {
        string pwdhash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "loginProcedure";

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@username", username);
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@password", pwdhash);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            return "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            return "no";
        }

  }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SnaprintWebserviceReferance.SnaPrintWebServiceSoapClient obj = new SnaprintWebserviceReferance.SnaPrintWebServiceSoapClient();

        obj.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<SnaprintWebserviceReferance.LoginCompletedEventArgs>(obj_LoginCompleted);
        obj.LoginAsync(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        //ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient clint = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
        //clint.phoneAsync(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

    }

    private void obj_LoginCompleted(object sender, SnaprintWebserviceReferance.LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.Result;
    }
```

Comment: **Don't store your passwords as a plain text**. Use [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash functions.

Comment: yes i did that 
        string pwdhash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");